# Fullcalendar is not displaying on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I have been trying to show events that are accociated with  contact on vf page using fullcalendar plugin, I am not getting any error but calendar is not getting displayed on vf page.

Controller in vf:

```
<apex:page controller="CalendarExample" action="{!pageload}" Showheader="false">

    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.fullCalendarcss}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.fullcalendarprintcss}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.fullcalendarmincss}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.fullcalendarminjs}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.fullcalendarjs}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.momentjs}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryuicustommin}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquerymin}" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="    //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        if (j$) {
            alert("yes");
        } else {
            alert("no");
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'

                },
                editable: false,
                events: [ <
                    apex: repeat value = "{!events}"
                    var = "e" > {
                        title: '{!e.title}',
                        start: '{!e.startString}',
                        end: '{!e.endString}',
                        url: '{!e.url}',
                        allDay: '!e.allDay}',

                    }, <
                    /apex:repeat>
                ]
            });

        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #cal-options {
            float: left;
        }

        #cal-legend {
            float: right;
        }

        #cal-legend ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

        #cal-legend ul li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px;
            float: left;
        }

        #cal-legend ul li span {
            display: block;
            height: 16px;
            width: 16px;
            margin-right: 4px;
            float: left;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        #calendar {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #calendar a:hover {
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        .fc-event-inner {
            padding: 3px;
        }

        .event-birthday {
            background: #56458c;
            border-color: #56458c;
        }

        .event-campaign {
            background: #cc9933;
            border-color: #cc9933;
        }

        .event-personal {
            background: #1797c0;
            border-color: #1797c0;
        }
    </style>

    <apex:sectionHeader title="My Calendar Events" />
    <apex:outputPanel id="calPanel">
        <apex:form>
            <div id="cal-options">
                <apex:commandButton value="{!IF(includeMyEvents,'Hide My Events','Show My Events')}" action="{!toggleMyEvents}" />
            </div>
            <div id="cal-legend">
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="event-birthday"></span>Contact's Birthdays</li>
                    <li><span class="event-campaign"></span>Campaigns</li>
                    <li style="{!IF(includeMyEvents,'','display:none')}"><span class="event-personal"></span>My Events</li>
                </ul>
                <div style="clear:both;">
                    <!--fix floats-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;">
                <!--fix floats-->
            </div>
            <div id="calendar"> <b>Calendar</b></div>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class CalendarExample {
    public Boolean includeMyEvents {get;set;}
    Public list < calEvent > events {get;set;}
    String dtFormat = 'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss';
    Public CalendarExample() {
        includeMyEvents = true;
    }
    Public pagereference pageload() {
        events = new list < calEvent > ();
        contact con = [select id from contact where lastname = 'kiran'];
        system.debug('--------------' + con);
        for (Event evnt: [select Id, Subject, isAllDayEvent, StartDateTime, EndDateTime from Event where whoid =: con.id]) {
            DateTime startDT = evnt.StartDateTime;
            DateTime endDT = evnt.EndDateTime;
            calEvent myEvent = new calEvent();
            myEvent.title = evnt.Subject;
            myEvent.allDay = evnt.isAllDayEvent;
            myEvent.startString = startDT.format(dtFormat);
            myEvent.endString = endDT.format(dtFormat);
            myEvent.url = '/' + evnt.Id;
            myEvent.className = 'event-personal';
            events.add(myEvent);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference toggleMyEvents() {
        if (includeMyEvents) {
            includeMyEvents = false;
        } else {
            includeMyEvents = true;
        }
        pageload();
        return null;
    }
    public class calEvent {
        public String title {get;set;}
        public Boolean allDay {get;set;}
        public String startString {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public String endString {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public String url {get;set;}
        public String className {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider standardStylesheets ="false" -- to remove the standard SF stylesheets that are overriding what ever the Calendar is doing. Also if that doesn't solve it, it start removing what SF adds to VF pages, like applyHtmlTag="false", applyBodyTag="false". That usually gets all the stuff out of there that throws off custom CSS and jQuery.

Comment: Check browser developer console for any JavaScript error.

Comment: @alphaBravo, No luck

Comment: Also start removing includescript and use just the normal script tag. Sometimes in includescript it will translate the JS incorrectly or load improperly. Also it looks like you are loading Jquery-min twice. I would do a compare on the calendars jquery min and the google hosted jquert min file

Answer (score 1):

Try removing some of the tags you have that create styling like these two in particular and replace them with standard html like divs, spans, H1s, etc.:

```
<apex:sectionHeader title="My Calendar Events" />
<apex:outputPanel id="calPanel">
```

These are limiting your page sizes. If you wrap everything in a `<div width = 100%>` or `<table width = 100%>` that should solve your issue. You might still need the output panel, but definitely not the section header. And definitely remove the standard stylesheets to see if you really need them!

Comment: @Sfdcprgmr That's an entirely different question. You're going to need an onClick event that has an associated method in your class that's called to create a New Event, saves it and then you requery the list of events for your Calendar. If this post led you to solving your issue, please help the rest of the community by using your other account to mark it as having answered your question.

Comment: Everything is doing fine but i dont know how to add new event in custom calendar on click on date.
So any idea how i can add new events ??
i follow this url  http://www.codebycody.com/2013/06/create-calendar-view-in-salesforcecom.html